# config file for a web server

Tags: file, config

I have written a simple web server in C. I **want to write a config** file that contains details like

```
web_root="rood_directory"

max_header_sizq="1024"
```

.....etc

How to and what are best practices to read and extract the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your config file is going to be compliant to normal INI definitions, which it looks like it might be, have you considered using one of the many .ini parsers available? See below, and of course, there's a lot more.

1. [libini](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libini/)
2. [minini](http://www.compuphase.com/minini.htm)
3. [inih](http://code.google.com/p/inih/)

Comment: it does not have to be compliant to INI definition. It is OK to be a simple text file. Do I have to read the file line by line and do some string matching stuff?

Comment: Why don't you make it compliant to a normal INI file? If you use a custom format, you'll need a custom parser - That's a given :-) INI Files are extremely simple to create, and what you've shown above as your example is **already** compatible with an INI file.

Comment: I linked to 3 different INI File parsers in my answer (each word is a different link). Sorry if that's confusing! :-P

Comment: If you really want to write your own parser, just read line by line and parse with regular expressions. I recommend the POSIX regex functions (regcomp/regexec).

Comment: Oh I did not noticed. I will have a look at it. Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

It might be total overkill, but I usually go with XML. It's relatively easy to write a parser based on libxml2 (with XPath), and you can have block nesting as much as you like.

But as I said, it might be overkill. INI is definitely much simpler.

Comment: If so, how to write it in INI method?

Comment: See rudi_visser's links in his post further up.